# MySQL create table in stored procedure error in PHPMyAdmin, Mysql ver: 5.7.33

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Here is the code what i want to compiling in PHPMyAdmin (MySQL ver: 5.7.33)

The goal is to copy a table for backup purposes. The name of the newly created table should include the current date's year, month, and day values. (dynamic sql)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE allomany_masolas(IN source_table VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_table VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE sql_code VARCHAR(255);
    
    SET new_table = CONCAT('given_table_name', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'));
    SET sql_code = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', new_table, ' AS SELECT * FROM ', source_table);
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM sql_code;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I can't find the problem (and the online MI agents neither) - Every time I get a syntax error message which is: #1064 - Syntax error near 'sql_code;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END' at line 9."

Could someone help me with a solution?" vagy "Can anyone help me figure out the solution?

I tried to find a syntax error, checked the mysql version's compatibility in commands (Despite this, it's possible that there is some version compatibility issue.)
I tried seeking advice on other forums, but I can't find the error in the code.

Comment: You must use not local variable but user-defined variable as SQL code in PREPARE. https://dbfiddle.uk/iqPnA3Up